# Get form data and put into a href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'd like to send a SMS on website by

```
<a href="sms:+12345678?body=form data"
```

and popup the SMS application on cellphone.

I'd like user to fill the form, javascript get form data and insert into body= in a link.

Does javascript or jquery can do it?

Here is the code I've tried with input
sms-link.min.js is for make SMS links compatible cross devices, but it only works on Android not iOS.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ca_no">
<div class="col-md-12"> <a href="sms:+4268800" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="location.href=this.href+'?body=EDS&nbsp;'+card_no;return false;">Register</a> </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sms-link.min.js"></script>
<script>
var card_no=document.getElementById('ca_no').value;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (function () {
        link = new SMSLink.link();
        link.replaceAll();
    }), false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

enter data and click link won't work, it will works when click back with same data which already filled.

Comment: Post your tried code please..

Comment: Hi, I haven't write the code yet but try to find the solution on the web. Right now there is only pass data from link to form. So I just wonder can it do backward.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in following manner:

- Put an event listener on button or anchor click that collects the    form data and out it in some variable.
- Make an ajax call to some server side scripting language with that stored data.
- From server side scripting language you can hit the SMS API with the specified   parameter using GET or POST method.

[Reference](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=246)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#ca_no").blur(function()
  {
  var card_no=$('#ca_no').val();  
  $("#register").text(card_no); //you can remove this
  $("#register").attr('href',window.location.href+'?body=EDS'+card_no);
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="ca_no">
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<a href="sms:+4268800" class="btn btn-warning" id="register">Register</a> 
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

Javascript and jquery can do that. but you need to clear what exactly you want to happen

please specify an example of output

Comment: When you are asking to put some relevant code or some thing else than it should be done in a comment, not in the answer.